# How do I calculate solutions of system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$x'=\begin{pmatrix}4 & -5\\-6 & -3\end{pmatrix}x$$ with $x=(x_1(t),x_2(t))^T$.
>
> Beginning values are: $x_1(0)=1,x_2(0)=0$

How do I calculate the general real solution of the differential equation system?

---

I get that eigenvalues are: $7,-6$.
The corresponding eigenvectors are $v_1=(5,−3)^T$ and $v_2=(1,2)^T$.

From the initial condition we get

$$(1,0)^T=c_1v_1+c_2v_2$$

Solving this equation yields $c_1=2/13$ and $c_2=3/13$ such that the final solution is
\begin{align}
x_1&=10/13·e^{7t}+3/13·e^{-6t} \\
x_2&=-6/13·e^{7t}+6/13·e^{-6t}
\end{align}

Is this good?

Comment: When I type this equations I don't get this in wolfram? @Moo